# How to determine the size of a model?

Tags: optimization, modeling, integer-programming, computational-complexity

I want to know about the number of variables and constraints of this formulation (exp: $o(n)$ variables and constraints or $o(n^2)$ ....).

Is the number of variables $\mathcal O(n^3)$ because we have three index variables with $N\times N\times N$?

How can I compute the complexity of the constraints step by step? I would be grateful if you have any other examples or references explaining this question.
[image]

Comment: Just out curiosity, what constrains the $z_t$ variables in this model?

Comment: Maybe $c_t$ is a typo for $z_t$?

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, you have to look at the variables' ranges.

- $z_t$ is defined $\forall t \in T$, so you have $|T| \in O(|T|)$ such variables;
- $y_i^k$ is defined $\forall i \in [1,n], \; \forall k \in [1,n]$, so you have $n^2 \in O(n^2)$ such variables;
- $x_{ij}^k$ is defined $\forall (i,j) \in [1,n]\times [1,n], i < j, \; \forall k \in [1,n]$, so you have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}n \in O(n^3)$ such variables;

So you end up with a total of $O(|T|)+ O(n^2) + O(n^3) = O(|T|)+ O(n^3)$ variables.

Likewise for constraints: you can see that you have $O(n^3)$ of them.

Comment: Thanks, so for the constraints I should focus on the summation part of the constraint or the belonging part?

Comment: It is not $o(n^3)$ for the constraints because we have used $i$, $j$ and $k$?

Comment: the belonging part. because each item of the "belonging part" is a distinct line (a separate constraint).

Comment: Yes indeed $O(n^3)$ for the constraints, because of constraints 2 and 3.

Comment: Could a formulation like this  with o(n3) variables and constraints consume less execution time than a flow formulation  with o(n2) variables and constraints ?

Comment: Not easy to say without more details on the model. But if I had to take a guess, I would say that the flow formulation with less variables and constraints is likely to be faster.

Comment: @Kuifje you have a couple of errors in the counts for $y$ and $x$, but the $O()$ doesn't change.

Comment: woops indeed! thanks. fixed for $y$. for $x$, I considered that $i=j$ was possible, which is wrong.

Comment: Closer, but should be $i<j$.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for spotting the small (but important) mistakes.

Comment: what are the errors for i and j ?

Comment: It’s been fixed. I had assumed $x$ was defined for all $(i,j)$, and not $i <j$. This did not change the fact that there were $O(n^3)$ $x$ variables.